# no me elimina elemento de la lista

Tags: python, lista, eliminar

Estoy tratando de eleminar los elementos de una lista siempre que contengan algun caracter numerico en el. El codigo que tengo funciona, al menos los detecta, pero a la hora de borrar me deja uno de ellos, podrian decirme mi error? gracias de antemano

```
a=["symbol","ETHB3TC","price","0.06715900","s1ymbol","LTCBTC","price","0.00266700"]

def has_numbers(inputString):
    return any(char.isdigit() for char in inputString)

for i in a:
    eck=has_numbers(i)
    print(eck)
```

si lo ejecuto asi me detecta todos los elementos con numeros sin problema alguno

salida:

```
False
True
False
True
True
False
False
True
```

pero si le digo que elimine los elementos, no los elimina todos:

```
for i in a:
    eck=has_numbers(i)
    if eck: 
        a.remove(i)
        
print(a)
```

salida:

```
['symbol', 'price', 's1ymbol', 'LTCBTC', 'price']
```

no entiendo por que no me elimina 's1ymbol', lo que mas me rompe el cerebro es que repito el bucle for si me lo elimina

EDIT:la respuesta a mi interrogante esta mas abajo, pero en caso de no querer crear una lista nueva se puede trabajar en reversa y con los indices asi:

```
for i in range(len(a)-1,-1,-1):
    eck=has_numbers(a[i])
    if eck: 
        del a[i]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te explico @Nigan, al eliminar los elementos de una lista que estas iterando los indices se van moviendo ejemplo:

```
a=["symbol","ETHB3TC","price","0.06715900","s1ymbol","LTCBTC","price","0.00266700"]
```

iteracion 1:

> "symbol" -> se mantiene en lista

iteracion 2:

> "ETHB3TC" -> se elimina de la lista

itercion 3:

> "0.06715900" -> Se elimina de la lista

**Como podras notar no es "price" por que su posición fu modificada y "0.06715900" tomo su lugar**

iteracion 4:

> "LTCBTC" -> se elimina de la lista

** Como podras ver no es "s1ymbol" ya que "LTCBTC" tomo su posición

iteracion 5:

> "price" -> no se elimina de la lista

iteracion 6:

> "0.00266700" -> Se elimina de la lista

El resulta final es el siguiente listado:

```
["symbol","price","s1ymbol","price"]
```

Es por eso que no se modifica una lista que se itera, se crea una nueva para almacenar los valores que necesitas

Mi solucion es crear una copia de la lista y eliminar los elementos de la copia

```
a = ["symbol","ETHB3TC","price","0.06715900","s1ymbol","LTCBTC","price","0.00266700"]
a_copy = a.copy()

def has_numbers(inputString):
    return any(char.isdigit() for char in inputString)

for i in a:
    eck = has_numbers(i)
    if eck:
        a_copy.remove(i)
```

Comment: Gracias, entendido, habia olvidado que en estos temas es mejor recorrer la lista en reversa, para no crear otra lista trabaje con los indices, lo resolvi con:
 for i in range(len(a)-1,-1,-1):
    eck=has_numbers(a[i])
    if eck: 
        del a[i]

Answer (score 2):

Como regla general, nunca modifiques aquello que estás iterando, ya sea una lista u otro contenedor.

El patrón estándar para alterar una lista mientras se la recorre es creando una segunda lista con los elementos seleccionados de la primera.

Dicho eso, la implementación es

```
lista = []
for i in a:
    eck=has_numbers(i)
    if not eck:
        lista.append(i)
```

Al terminar, `lista` contiene los elementos deseados.

Esto tiene un efecto mínimo en el consumo de memoria, pues los elementos mismos no se duplican. La nueva lista (igual que la original) sólo contiene las referencias a esos elementos (*punteros*).

#### Demo

```
a=["symbol","ETHB3TC","price","0.06715900","s1ymbol","LTCBTC","price","0.00266700"]

def has_numbers(inputString):
    return any(char.isdigit() for char in inputString)

lista = []
for i in a:
    eck=has_numbers(i)
    if not eck:
        lista.append(i)

print(lista)
```

produce:

```
['symbol', 'price', 'LTCBTC', 'price']

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: entiendo, pero no se deberia modificar por que? bucaba no estar creando tantas variables ya que si sigo el consejo, deberia de tener el doble de variables, lo que ademas de incomodo a la vista imagino sea menos eficiente, no quita que tu codigo funciona, pero el mio "deberia" funcionar creo yo

Comment: Estuve buscando la documentación de respaldo, pero no encontré nada pertinente. Este problema surge con frecuencia y debería haber una respuesta predefinida. Voy a trabajar en eso.

Comment: Tu preocupación por la eficiencia no se justifica. Los elementos sólo existen una vez, sin importar en cuantas listas aparezcan. Además, el manejo de listas es hiper-eficiente en Python.

Comment: Piensa en las variables y las posiciones en las listas como nombres. Si, tiene un impacto en la eficiencia, pero muy chico. Llamar al mismo arbol de distintas formas no crea un bosque. Asi que concuerdo con Candid Moe que tu preocupacion por la eficiencia no se justifica. Te vas a complicar al cohete.

Comment: En cuanto a cosas como lo visual. Me parece mas incomodo y menos claro visualmente recorrer un rango a la inversa para modificar una lista. Es mejor crear una nueva lista y ya. Pero si te molesta crear una variable como lista2 y lista = lista2, la mayoria de las veces se resuelve con comprension de lista.

Answer (score 0):

Muy en resumen:

En un bucle for, si añades o eliminas elementos de una lista durante su ejecución, el "contador interno" del bucle se ve afectado haciendo que en la siguiente iteración se salte el siguiente elemento que estaba predeterminado si no modificases nada.

Para este tipo de casos lo mejor es empezar por el final de la lista e ir descendiendo

```py
for i in range(len(lista)-1 , -1, -1):
    if True:
        lista.remove(i)
```